# Tristate checkbox in Office ribbon

Tags: vba, ribbonx

Is there a way to have a tri-state checkbox on MS office 2016 ribbons?

Comment: No, the Ribbon UI doesn't provide that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The Fluent UI has a limited number of controls with a pre-defined functionality. You can find all the ribbon UI controls described in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12))

The `checkBox` control provides the `getPressed` callback which returns boolean:

```
C#: bool GetPressed(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnValue)
C++: HRESULT GetPressed([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfPressed)
Visual Basic: Function GetPressed(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

There is no third state.